# Mac application to download, verify (through md5), and run another large application

Tags: macos, bootcamp, install, dmg

I have spent quite some time Googling for a specific product solution that I cannot seem to find for the life of me, so I come to Stack Exchange for some help.

I work for an unmentioned public university in which a certain group of incoming freshman students are required to purchase a new laptop and one of the options they have is a specific configuration of a 13" Macbook Pro. We are forecasting that approximately 1,800 students will be aquiring these Macbooks over the next few months before the Fall semester begins in August.

The issue we have is they are required to use some specific software that is only available in Windows. We have found a product solution that runs a simple .dmg file and partitions the existing hard drive as such to install a pre-configured Windows image in Boot Camp which includes this required software. This way the student is not required to perform any tasks that are outside their scope of technical knowledge, seeing as Boot Camp can at times be a bit confusing.

**The solution I am looking for is an application or method that performs the following;**

1. Downloading that potentially large .dmg file (in excess of 40 GB)
   without the student having to enter any input, such as where the
   file is located on the internet
2. Verifying the file through an md5
   checksum
3. If possible, automatically executing that .dmg file

Comment: A dmg is a disk image (like an USB stick), so you can kind of plug it in (to stay with the USB stick analogy) but you can't execute it as such. Is there an application you want to run which is stored in the image? Or is the image the Bootcamp partition you want to install?

Comment: @patrix I have not been able to get my hands on this program yet but from what I understand, you would mount the .dmg file, run the application, and follow a few prompts GUI prompts to begin the configuring of the local disk and install of the Windows image.

Comment: @patrix To clarify, this program is a fully licensed software designed for the purpose of cloning Windows installs for deployment on Macs. I just need an easy way to get it to the students.

Comment: Die you contact the vendor regarding this? They are in the best position to help you here (and might even provide a custom built version). GUI scripting is possible but tricky to get fail and fool proof, you probably would have less issues if you provided clear instructions for the users.

Comment: The problem with this idea is that this application *needs to be tailor made* for this exact purpose. Most applications you find outside would be built to be general-purpose, and it's unlikely you'd find something so specialised.

Comment: @perhapsmaybeharry The idea I had was if there was an application that existed to build a cusom tailored dmg file that would accomplish this on a specific pre-set URL.